# item of recyclerView scroll to outside of recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

when i scroll my recyclerView , item move to outside it like this:
[image]
this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar_chat_details"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#fff"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
       app:menu="@menu/menu_chat_details"
       app:title="toolbarChatDetails">
       <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <ImageButton
               android:id="@+id/button_back_chat_details"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@android:color/transparent"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
           <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
               android:id="@+id/image_user_chat_details"
               android:layout_width="36dp"
               android:layout_height="36dp"
               android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
               android:src="@drawable/avatar"
               app:civ_border_color="#515050"
               app:civ_border_overlay="true"
               app:civ_border_width="1dp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button_back_chat_details"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/username_chat_details"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
               android:text="China Girl"
               android:textColor="@color/black"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/image_user_chat_details"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
       </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
   <View
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="2dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_chat_details"
       android:background="#525252"/>

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/rcv_chat_details"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@id/layout_message"
       android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_chat_details" />

   <View
       android:id="@+id/view_bottom"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:layout_above="@id/layout_message"
       android:background="#AAAAAA"/>
   <RelativeLayout
       android:padding="8dp"
       android:id="@+id/layout_message"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_send_message_chat_details"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <ImageButton
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               android:id="@+id/button_send_image_chat_details"
               android:layout_width="36dp"
               android:visibility="visible"
               android:layout_height="36dp"
               android:background="@android:color/transparent"
               android:src="@drawable/ic_picture" />
           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/edt_send_message"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="32dp"
               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
               android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_send_image_chat_details"
               android:background="@drawable/border_edt_chat_details"
               android:backgroundTint="#F2F0F0"
               android:hint="Type..."
               android:paddingStart="8dp"
               android:textColor="@color/black"
               android:textSize="18sp" />
       </RelativeLayout>
       <ImageButton
           android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:id="@+id/button_send_message_chat_details"
           android:layout_width="36dp"
           android:visibility="invisible"
           android:layout_height="36dp"
           android:background="@android:color/transparent"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_send" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

i don't have a idea to fix it, please help me!

**You’ve gotta dance like there’s nobody watching, love like you’ll never be hurt, sing like there’s nobody listening, and live like it’s heaven on earth. ― William W. Purkey**

**have a nice day,everyone!**

Answer (score 1):

Set `android:layout_height` to 0dp for the `RecyclerView`

Comment: this not work, do you have another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are using RelativeLayout as parent . You have two option now :

1 . using LinearLayout with vertical orientation instead of RelativeLayout

2 . use marginTop & marginBottom on RecyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
       android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
       android:id="@+id/rcv_chat_details"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_above="@id/layout_message"
       android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_chat_details" />
```

Comment: i like to use RelativeLayout than LinearLayout. but how i can calculate actionBarSize. i use wrap-content for height's actionBar.

Comment: Have a look on XML code that i shared with you . you can use ?actionBarSize instead of wrap content . its return standard size of toolbar . I suggest you to add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" on parent layer of your activity